# logstash 5.0 ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to install a ELK stack to read from apache access logs.

I have installed Kibana and Elasticsearch from the documentation, and they are running successfully. However when I got to the Logstash installation, I have installed it, but when I run the upstart command to run as a service it doesn't seem to be working.

[This is the Logstash documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/installing-logstash.html)

I am getting this when doing the `update && install logstash` command:

```
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/artifacts.elastic.co_packages_5.x_apt_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 1438 1659
```

When I run the command `sudo initctl start logstash`, I get this in the `/var/log/logstash/logstash-plain.log`:

```
[2016-11-08T10:39:19,671][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] failed to fetch pipeline configuration {:message=>"No config files found: /etc/logstash/conf.d/*\nCan you make sure this path is a logstash config file?"}
[2016-11-08T11:05:08,863][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>["http://localhost:9200"]}}
[2016-11-08T11:05:09,009][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
[2016-11-08T11:05:09,676][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>50001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"_all"=>{"enabled"=>true, "norms"=>false}, "dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "mat$
[2016-11-08T11:05:09,816][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Installing elasticsearch template to _template/logstash
[2016-11-08T11:05:10,037][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["localhost:9200"]}
[2016-11-08T11:05:10,432][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>8, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>1000}
[2016-11-08T11:05:10,449][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline main started
[2016-11-08T11:05:10,839][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2016-11-08T11:05:30,798][WARN ][logstash.runner          ] SIGINT received. Shutting down the agent.
[2016-11-08T11:05:30,807][WARN ][logstash.agent           ] stopping pipeline {:id=>"main"}
```

It seems to have ran once and I cannot get it to start or restart or do anything, what have I missed?

The documentation says that this should happen, which it doesn't seem to be happening:

```
The auto-generated configuration file for upstart systems is /etc/init/logstash.conf.
```

I just looked in the `/etc/logstash/startup.options` and in the heading it says that if anything changes run `/usr/share/logstash/bin/system-install` to update the init startup script. I am getting this error if I manually run the `./system-install`:

```
Sending all logs to /tmp/tmp.cSTnSWDf4d
NoMethodError: undefined method `tr' for nil:NilClass
   detect_upstart at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/pleaserun-0.0.24/lib/pleaserun/detector.rb:45
  detect_platform at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/pleaserun-0.0.24/lib/pleaserun/detector.rb:24
           detect at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/pleaserun-0.0.24/lib/pleaserun/detector.rb:18
   setup_defaults at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/pleaserun-0.0.24/lib/pleaserun/cli.rb:141
          execute at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/pleaserun-0.0.24/lib/pleaserun/cli.rb:107
              run at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:67
              run at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:132
           (root) at /usr/share/logstash/lib/systeminstall/pleasewrap.rb:12
Unable to install system startup script for Logstash.
```

Comment: did you see this: `No config files found: /etc/logstash/conf.d/*` -- do you have any config files in that directory for it to process?

Comment: Hi, thanks sorry I should of excluded that line that was from a previous error, I since added the config file to the start script. So the error was after that.